# Continued fraction: Closed form solution

Tags: closed-form, fractions, continued-fractions

Community,

I am new to this forum but found some of your posts very interesting in the past. I'm stuck in a problem related to continued fractions. In particular, the continued fraction is perturbed by the elements of $y_1$.

My problem:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co0gh.png)

> Is there any possible way to derive closed form expressions of $g$ and $h$ in terms of $x$, $y_1$, and $y_2$? There are $n$ fractions.

\begin{equation}
    \cfrac{g}{h}=\cfrac{\frac{x}{y_1}}{1-\cfrac{x}{y_1}\cfrac{\frac{x}{y_2}}{1-\cfrac{x}{y_2}\cfrac{\frac{x}{y_2}}{\ddots \phantom{=}\cfrac{\vdots}{1-\cfrac{x}{y_2}\cfrac{\frac{x}{y_2}}{1-\cfrac{x}{y_2}\cfrac{\frac{x}{y_2}}{1-\cfrac{x}{y_1}\cfrac{x}{y_2}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
I would be thankful for any hint or advice. Thank you in advance.

Best regards
Josef

Comment: Can you check the image ? ... I am getting a blank

Comment: Hello, is it visible now?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula